# MAX Function and Group BY in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have dataset coming in below format. As you can see for Chase ID 522723, I have 2 dates viz 29/06 and 09/07. At present a single chase ID is going onto both the buckets as it is considering both the dates, I need to bring in the MAX date filtered out by Chase ID and Project ID.

Hence in below example, the bucket for chase ID for 522723 should be "QC".

[image]

I have tried below seen measure

[image]

This measure is giving me said result (see below) which is bringing incorrect result set

[image]

Can someone please assist me in creating MAX measure so that it "*groups*" by using ChaseID.

Comment: @mkRabbani Requesting your input :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using FILTER with CALCULATE in this case should be unnecessary, since CALCULATE already comes with Filters. Also using ALL will give you the MAX result of, well all the results. Use ALLEXCEPT and you will get results grouped by ChaseID.

Like this:

```
CALCULATE(MAX(CODINGTABLE[BLCreatedDate]),ALLEXCEPT(CODINGTABLE;CODINGTABLE[ChaseID]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the share but it seems the code doesn't seem to recognize anything added after ";".. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's my european settings. Replace ; with , for CALCULATE(MAX(CODINGTABLE[BLCreatedDate]),ALLEXCEPT(CODINGTABLE,CODINGTABLE[ChaseID]))

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this doesn't work. Refer "Measure 6" in image
https://imgur.com/bpT6OJG

Comment: Impossible. :-) Did you use MAX(CODINGTABLE[BLCreatedDate].[Date] like in your original measure, or my suggestion MAX(CODINGTABLE[BLCreatedDate])? If you use .[Date] in this model, I think it will just fetch the MAX date of the Calender.

Comment: Yeah.. I used ".DATE".. Let me try without using the .[Date]